# What software do i need to create a flash file

Tags: flash

I am using `Asp.net/C#` to build an application , i have a requirement wherein i need to access webcam from my page and capture images of users.So i am trying to achieve this by creating flash file , can anybody suggest me software to create flash file , will flashmx help me.
Any suggestions are much appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try FlashDevelop.

- http://www.flashdevelop.org/

Which is a free editor for Flash, and Action Script.

Comment: ,, flashmx will serve my purpose , do you think so

Comment: you can develop flashmx in flashdevelop !

Answer (score 1):

Adobe Flash is the official way to create flash files.